# Joining a Table with Itself with multiple WHERE statemetns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Long time reader, first time poster.

I'm trying to consolidate a table I have to the rate of sold goods getting lost in transit. In this table, we have four kinds of products, three countries of origin, three transit countries (where the goods are first shipped to before being passed to customers) and three destination countries. The table is as follows.

```
 Status         Product    Count    Origin    Transit     Destination
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delivered      Shoes      100      Germany   France        USA
 Delivered      Books      50       Germany   France        USA
 Delivered      Jackets    75       Germany   France        USA
 Delivered      DVDS       30       Germany   France        USA
 Not Delivered  Shoes      7        Germany   France        USA
 Not Delivered  Books      3        Germany   France        USA
 Not Delivered  Jackets    5        Germany   France        USA
 Not Delivered  DVDS       1        Germany   France        USA
 Delivered      Shoes      300      Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Delivered      Books      80       Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Delivered      Jackets    25       Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Delivered      DVDS       90       Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Not Delivered  Shoes      17       Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Not Delivered  Books      13       Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Not Delivered  Jackets    1        Poland    Netherlands   Canada
 Delivered      Shoes      250      Spain     Ireland       UK
 Delivered      Books      20       Spain     Ireland       UK
 Delivered      Jackets    150      Spain     Ireland       UK
 Delivered      DVDS       60       Spain     Ireland       UK
 Not Delivered  Shoes      19       Spain     Ireland       UK
 Not Delivered  Books      8        Spain     Ireland       UK
 Not Delivered  Jackets    8        Spain     Ireland       UK
 Not Delivered  DVDS       10       Spain     Ireland       UK
```

I would like to create a new table that shows the count of goods delivered and not delivered in one row, like this.

```
Product   Delivered   Not_Delivered   Origin    Transit      Destination
Shoes     100         7               Germany   France       USA
Books     50          3               Germany   France       USA
Jackets   75          5               Germany   France       USA
DVDS      30          1               Germany   France       USA
Shoes     300         17              Poland    Netherlands  Canada
Books     80          13              Poland    Netherlands  Canada
Jackets   25          1               Poland    Netherlands  Canada
DVDS      90          0               Poland    Netherlands  Canada
Shoes     250         19              Spain     Ireland      UK
Books     20          8               Spain     Ireland      UK
Jackets   150         8               Spain     Ireland      UK
DVDS      60          10              Spain     Ireland      UK
```

I've had a look at some other posts and so far I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. Perhaps the issue here is that there will be multiple WHERE statements in the code to ensure that I don't group all shoes together, ore all country groups.

Is this possible with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select
product
,sum(case when status = 'Delivered' then count else 0 end) as delivered
,sum(case when status = 'Not Delivered' then count else 0 end) as not_delivered
,origin
,transit
,destination

from table

group by
product
,origin
,transit
,destination
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy; instead of one line per Product, Origin, Transit, Destination and Status, you want one result line per Product, Origin, Transit and Destination only. So group by these four columns and aggregate conditionally:

```
select 
  product, origin, transit, destination,
  sum(case when status = 'Delivered' then "count" else 0 end) as delivered,
  sum(case when status = 'Not Delivered' then "count" else 0 end) as not_delivered
from mytable
group by product, origin, transit, destination;
```

BTW: It is not a good idea to use a keyword for a column name. I used double quotes to use your column `count`, which is standard SQL, but I don't know if it works in Google BigQuery. Maybe it must be `"Count"` rather than `"count"` or something entirely else.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  product, origin, transit, destination,
  SUM([count] * (status = 'Delivered')) AS delivered,
  SUM([count] * (status = 'Not Delivered')) AS not_delivered
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```